# How do I install Ubuntu on an Intel iMac with no OS nor CD drive

Tags: ubuntu, usb, boot, imac, img

What I want:

- Linux on an Intel iMac (Core Duo).

What I have:

- An empty PC (17" Intel iMac) with broken CD drive. It's model A1173.
- This PC with Ubuntu 12.04 and an old Windows Vista partition.
- a USB flash drive and an Ubuntu ISO.

Problems:

- No CD means the only boot drive I could use is USB.
- There is no BIOS on Macs, so I can't set boot settings or even see if it detects my USB drive. When I start the machine and press <kbd>Option</kbd>, the first and only thing I see is an old corrupted Windows XP partition and not a single option or additional information.
- So assuming blindly that the Mac hardware/firmware works normally, I don't have any Mac OS to use any of the tools that I found on different tutorials for building a bootable drive for Macs.
- I can't find much software on Linux/Windows to substitute to those tools, for example among others converting an .iso file (Win/Linux) to .img (Mac I guess). Which makes me think that the scenario where someone like me has Mac hardware but no Mac OS is extremely rare.
- So other than finding someone that has a Mac I have no solution. So I ask, what would you do? The only thing is it should not involve any money (I know Mac software is rarely free) which also excludes getting any Mac OS unless I can use a free macos.img for VM or restore the original Mac for free.

Comment: disk mode would help, maybe, if you had firewire connectors and a cable on both. This does seem tricky

Comment: This question was cross-posted on Apple.SE: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53512/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-on-a-imac-g5-with-no-os-nor-cd-drive

Comment: ugh, unfortunately the changes made invalidate both current answers :/

Answer (score 3):

Here is the approach I would take.  At least initially, as I haven't myself been in that situation before.  Start looking for a suitable PPC version of Linux.

I prefer Debian flavors so I would maybe take a look at either the [Debian PPC](http://www.debian.org/ports/powerpc/) or [Ubuntu PPC](http://www.debian.org/ports/powerpc/) releases to begin with.

Next, get yourself a nice little utility to make your USB device bootable.  I have had success with [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) as well as the [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).  However, as said before I haven't had any experience with your scenario so I am not 100% sure there is support for PPC based distros built in, that is something you will have to experiment with.

I believe you can hold down the option key when the Mac is booting and get it to list the devices it can boot to.  From there you *should* be able to get into the Linux installer.  Again, maybe not the best approach but I guess I don't know where else you can go with what you've got.

Comment: unetbootin is another good tool for bootable usbs. If one tool fails, try with another one.

Comment: Good call, forgot about unetbootin.  It may be a viable option because it has Linux and Windows support.

Comment: Why Debian PPC? The question asks about an Intel Mac.